# How to retrieve fields value from Kendo Grid Models using ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, kendo-grid

How can I get posted field values from a Kendo model on the server end? I have a logger on the server end. This shows I received all of the fields, with column names and values. However, I am not sure how to retrieve those values:

**Used Script:**

```
 <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var crudServiceBaseUrl = "http://localhost:8500/test/test1.cfc?method=",
                        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                            transport: {
                                read:  {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl+"JsonRead",
                                    dataType: "json"                                    
                                },
                                create: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl+"JsonCreate",
                                    dataType: "json"
                                },
                                 parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                        return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                                    }
                                    return options;
                                }
                            },
                            batch: true,
                            pageSize: 20,
                            schema: {
                                type: "json",
                                model: {
                                    id: "productid",
                                    fields: {
                                        productid: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                        productname: { validation: { required: true } },
                                        unitprice: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1} },
                                        discontinued: { type: "boolean" },
                                        unitsinstock: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0, required: true } }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: dataSource,
                        pageable: true,
                        height: 430,
                        toolbar: ["create"],
                        columns: [
                            "productname",
                            { field: "unitprice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "100px" },
                            { field: "unitsinstock", title:"Units In Stock", width: "100px" },
                            { field: "discontinued", width: "100px" },
                            { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "172px" }],
                        editable: "inline"
                    });
                });
</script>
```

**test1.cfc**

```
    <cfcomponent>
<cffunction name="init">
<cfreturn this>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="JsonRead" returntype="any" description="Return all Product" access="remote">  
 <cfquery name="getallproducts" datasource="DataSource">       
     SELECT * from Products
    </cfquery>

    <cfset var aTmp = arraynew(1)>     
    <cfif getallproducts.recordcount>     
        <cfloop query="getallproducts"> 
            <cfset stTmp = structNew()> 
            <cfloop list="#lcase(getallproducts.columnlist)#" index="col"> 
            <cfset stTmp[col] = getallproducts[col][currentRow]> 
            </cfloop>
            <cfset arrayAppend(aTmp,stTmp)> 
        </cfloop> 
     <cfelse> 
        <cfset stTmp = structNew()> 
            <cfloop list="#lcase(getallproducts.columnlist)#" index="col"> 
                <cfset stTmp[col] = ""> 
            </cfloop>      
            <cfset arrayAppend(aTmp,stTmp)> 
     </cfif> 

  <cfset ss=#SerializeJSON(aTmp)#>

    <cfreturn ss>

</cffunction>

<cffunction name="JsonCreate" returntype="void" description="Create New Row" access="remote">   
            <cfargument name="models" type="string" required="yes">           
            <cfset data = urldecode(arguments.models)>
            <cfset data = deserializeJSON(data, false)>
</cffunction>


</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: yours is an invalid json representation ,why you do stringify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is a way to get at the data coming from your Kendo Grid once you save, update or delete. Here is an example of something you could do to loop through the data stored in the models argument coming from Kendo. Keep in mind if you set `batch` in your grid equal to `true` then you will have multiple rows of data coming from your grid.

```
remote void function JsonCreate(string models) output="false" {
    var data = urldecode(arguments.models);
    data = deserializeJSON(data, false);
}
```

EDIT: Example JsonRead Function below. If you don't specify return type as `string` ans `returnformat` as `plain` you have to set the return type to `any` and the `returnformat` to `JSON`.

```
remote string function JsonRead(string RemoteToken) returnFormat="plain" output="false" {
    if ( TestToken(arguments.RemoteToken) ) {
        return serializeJSON(QueryToStruct(QueryAllUsers()));
    }
}
```

I also use `dataType` as `JSON` so your datasource would look something like this:

```
var serviceURL = kendoURL + "/services/Service.cfc?RemoteToken=" + RemoteToken + "&method=",

    dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({

        transport: {

            read:  {

                url: serviceURL + "JsonRead",

                dataType: "JSON"
            },

            update: {
                url: serviceURL + "JsonUpdate",

                dataType: "JSON"
            },

            destroy: {

                url: serviceURL + "JsonDelete",

                dataType: "JSON"
            },

            create: {

                url: serviceURL + "JsonCreate",

                dataType: "JSON"
            },

            parameterMap: function(options, operation) {

                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {

                    return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                }
            }
        },

        batch: true
...
```

Also, since this will have to be a remote function you'll want to provide some sort of security check to guard against unauthorized access. I use a `RemoteToken` shown above.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was try the way as you suggest above, but din't get success to call cfc and there method. I have updated the script and file as above. Can you please review and let me know where i am wrong?

Comment: @sam, see edits above. Also the create function is not completely fleshed out, because there a hundred ways to process the data once you get it, but getting the data to that point should get you started.